# There is a problem displaying the image on my mobile, but the image is well displayed on Android Emulator

Tags: android

I use the base 64 method to convert the image into a string and then store it using the retrofit in the database and call it well and it is displayed in the in Android emulator, but after converting it into a APK in Mobile not seen
 apiInterface = login_client.getApiClient().create(login_interface.class);

```
    retrofit2.Call<Info> call = apiInterface.getinfo(strimage);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Info>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Info> call, Response<Info> response) {

            strimage=response.body().getImgnameinfo();
            Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, strimage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imagtest.setImageBitmap(StringToBitMap(strimage));
            imagtest.bringToFront();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Info> call, Throwable t) {

        }

    });
```

public static Bitmap StringToBitMap(String image) {

```
    try {
        byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(image.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
     final   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0,
                encodeByte.length);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more information? for example, what version of android you have in your emulator and what version of android on the phone you are testing.

Additionally, you added the following permissions in the `AndroidManifiest.xml` file to`<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` and `<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If bitmap size is too much image view won't be able to display it. You can scale the bitmap manually to lower the size before setting into the imageview or use some library like glide to load bitmap.

[Using Glide to set bitmap into an imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40625641/2797847)

[Load bitmap efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap)

Comment: No,Unfortunately

Comment: size image is small

Comment: I used your code but still I could not show on mobile.

Comment: What's the image size in terms of memory and resolution?

Comment: Use this to get size `int bitmapByteCount=BitmapCompat.getAllocationByteCount(bitmap)`

Comment: tank you.what  type use for   field in image in mysql?

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I think the size of the image was large

Comment: Great that you figured it out. If my answer was helpful please accept :)